# Proving Bound on Expected Value of Sup of Sequence of R.V.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, expectation

I am trying to prove the following:

Let ${X_n}$ be a sequence of non-negative independent random variables.  Show that:

$E(\sup X_{n}) \le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} E(X_{n}^{2})+1$,

where the sup is taken over the index n.

Not sure how to tackle this problem.

Answer (score 3):

If $b_1,b_2,\ldots$ are non-negative reals, then $\sup_nb_n\le \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n^2 +1$.

Comment: I've never seen this before.  Do you happen to have a simple proof?

Comment: So independence isn't necessary?

Comment: If the supremum is at most $1$, then the inequality is trivially true. Any $b_n$ that is greater than $1$ satisfies $b_n\le b_n^2$, which is in turn at most the infinite series.

Comment: The assumed independence is not needed.

Comment: So since $b_{n} \le b_{n}^{2} \le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_{n}^2 +1$, then $E(\sup X_{n}) \le E(\sum X_{n}^{2} +1) = \sum E(X_{n}^{2}) +1$.

Comment: @user75514 No, $b_n\le b_n^2$ is not always true. Please read more carefully John's first comment.